# Reference book on Kronecker set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, baire-category

I am self-reading the lecture notes Baire Category, Probabilistic Constructions and Convolution Squares by T.W. Korner.
[https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Baire.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Etwk/Baire.pdf)

In chapter 4, he mentioned the Kronecker set with little explanation. Can I ask what references textbook is good to know these stuffs, such as Kronecker approximation theorem, etc?

Comment: There aren’t any AFAIK. This terminology is Korner’s own.

Comment: You can see the following:

 [Geometric and Analytic Number Theory][1] by Edmund Hlawka, Rudolf Taschner & Johannes Schoißengeier


  [1]: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-75306-0

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, the book you mentioned covers only the Kronecker approximation theorem in the number theory setting. Is there any other book covering the topic of the Kronecker set? In particular, I wonder why the Kronecker set is said to be "thin" in the one-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: Maybe [**Thin Sets in Harmonic Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com//dp/0824713176) edited by Lindahl/Poulsen (1971). Kronecker sets occur in many of the (individually authored) chapters. For your purpose, probably the most useful would be **Chapter I.** *Dirichlet, Kronecker and Helson sets* by Lindahl on pp. 1-19, and **Chapter III.** *Harmonic synthesis of Kronecker sets* by Tewari on pp. 29-40, and **Chapter XIII.** *Relations between Dirichlet, Kronecker and Helson sets* by Körner on pp. 148-160.

Comment: Thank you so much!